# Read data from excel and retrieve related data from text file using Java POI and display result in another excel

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to read a particular column data from Excel file and search for the related title of column in a text file which has additional data.I want to print those details back to another excel file using Java poi.
My data looks like:

**Excel:**

```
Name  Number
ABC   2345
XYZ   6789
```

**Text File:**

```
Name|Class|School
 ABC|1|bnm
 XYZ|2|hjk
 KOP|3|ert
```

**I want output in excel as:**

```
Name  Class  School
ABC   1      bnm
XYZ   2      hjk





 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String filename = System.getProperty("D:/Files/Input.xslx");
        List sheetData = new ArrayList();
        String columnWanted = "Name";
        Integer columnNo = null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
           XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Row firstRow = sheet.getRow(0);
            for(Cell cell:firstRow){
                if (cell.getStringCellValue().equals(columnWanted)){
                    columnNo = cell.getColumnIndex();
                }
            }
            if (columnNo != null){
            for (Row row : sheet) {
               Cell c = row.getCell(columnNo);
               if (c == null || c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                  // Nothing in the cell in this row, skip it
               } else {
                   sheetData.add(c);
                               }
              }System.out.println(sheetData);
            }else{
                System.out.println("could not find column ");
            }
    // Taking a new array list 'arr' for printing result data
            List arr =new ArrayList();
            File f=new File("D:/Files/Details.txt");
            Scanner in=new Scanner(f);
            System.out.println("Read Data From The Txt file ");
            while(in.hasNext())
            {    
    arr.add(in.nextLine());
                        }
            System.out.println(arr);
            }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        }
     }
        }



 I want help in searching Names in text file taking input from Input.xslx
```

Comment: I have tried to retrieve the excel data and keep it into an array.not able to link that data and search it in a text file

Comment: I meant: show us the code..

Comment: Was there enough information in my answer?  Do you need further guidance?

Answer (score 0):

The general approach I'd take would be:

1. Split the rows of the text file: `String[] textRow = in.nextLine().split("\\|");`
2. If `sheetData.contains(textRow[0])` is true, then create the three new cells using Poi.

As an aside, I'd create a new worksheet in the same workbook for writing the new cells to.  You can move the cells later if you want.  It means that, while testing, you can delete the new worksheet after each experiment, and your "source" worksheet won't have been modified.